# How to extract an integer from a varchar without creating an error

Tags: postgresql, integer, varchar

I am required to build a query and provide a list of classes with number of students and type of students. However in this particular school, one class can contain one or more school levels. For example some students tend to be taught in the same class between certain school levels. e.g. certain handicapped students. Special students can be taught with rest of the students.
I need a dominant school level from that class. The only way to retrieve that level is based on the class name.
So I have the following table

| Class | No.ofStudents | School Levels | No.ofSpecialStudents | No.ofhandicappedstudents |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 25 | 0,1 | 5 | 0 |
| 1B | 22 | 0,1 | 7 | 0 |
| 2A | 26 | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 2B | 23 | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 3A | 28 | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 3B | 27 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| NVSK | 12 | 0,1,2 | 0 | 12 |

This top list is a sample of what I have. Now I need to the produce the list as follows

| Class | MainSchoollevel | No.ofStudents | SchoolLevels | No.ofSp.Students | No.ofHCstudents |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 1 | 25 | 0,1 | 5 | 0 |
| 1B | 1 | 22 | 0,1 | 7 | 0 |
| 2A | 2 | 26 | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 2B | 2 | 23 | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 3A | 3 | 28 | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 3B | 3 | 27 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| NVSK | null | 12 | 0,1,2 | 0 | 12 |

How would I be able to create a field called Main school Level (type int) that could extract the first value from the classname and then turn it into a number field?

As you might have noticed there is also a class named 'NVSK' in the list, that cannot be translated into a number, so how would I be able to place a null value instead? What technique would best be used for this situation?

Here is the form of the query

```
select c.shortname as Classname, //varchar type
                       // as "MainSchoolLevel"
       count(s.studentid) as "No.ofStudents",
       string_agg(distinct cast(l.shorttext as varchar(4)), ', ') as "SchoolLevels",
       sum(case when s.specialstudent true then 1 else 0 end) as "No.ofSpecialStudents",
       sum(case when s.handicappedstudent true then 1 else 0 end) as "No.ofhandicappedStudents",
       
 from student s
 join studentclass sc on sc.studentid = sc.id
 join class c on c.id = sc.classid
 join classlevel cl on cl.classid = c.id
 join level on l.id = cl.levelid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to extract values by regular expression and assign them to new columns

```sql
select
  class,
  (coalesce (substring (class, '^\d+'), '') as num_class,
  (coalesce (substring (class, '[A-Za-z]+'), '') as str_class,
from student s ....
```